# grid layout not working, container taking full screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put two tables in a web page  using 10% margin left, 60% space, and 30 % space. Initially I have created a container but if I'm changing the parameter, the width of that does not change. It is occupying the whole screen width.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3" style="border:solid black; background-color:red;">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
   
<div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-6" style="border:solid black; background-color:green;">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where do you set the width in your code? I could be missing it, but I don't see it in the code you provided.

Comment: @Zim is my code correct now ?

Comment: @Chipster will this class="col-sm-6 " determine the width ?

Comment: What is the `10% margin left, 60% space, and 30 % space` CSS?

Comment: @zim let's say that width is 100 unit i want 10 unit margin left side  and 60 unit for first column and 30 unit for second column

Comment: I think I was missing something. I didn't realize you're using Bootstrap. I'm not familiar with Bootstrap, so that is very possible that that class has that defined behavior. However, if Bootstrap doesn't define that class, then you will need to include the CSS for that class. Otherwise, nothing we can see is setting the width property of the element.

Comment: @chipster can u help me with css

Comment: I can try, but I would need to see your CSS. Though I'm slightly concerned that I'm out of my element here. I'm not super familiar with Bootstrap. I'm more familiar with vanilla HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Zim thnx i dint use the css link .but now problem is that offset not working

Comment: It works as expected: https://codeply.com/p/QjZunKVFBE ... also `col-*-6` doesn't mean 60% and `col-*-3` doesn't mean 30% .. do you understand that?

Answer (score 0):

The grid system consider 12 columns so you can approximate your values like below:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-7 offset-1" style="border:solid black; background-color:red;"> 10% of 12 is 1.2 and 60% of 12 is 7.2 </div>
   
<div class="col-4" style="border:solid black; background-color:green;"> 30% of 12 is 3.6 so we use 4</div>
    </div>
```